# urllib2.urlopen() returning a different result

Tags: python

I'm trying to fill out a form using a python program, it works well for some sites, but not this particular one, i'm not sure why.

this is the code snipet

```
query = {
'adults':'1',
'children':'0',
'infants':'0',
'trip':'RT',
'deptCode':'LOS',
'arrvCode':'ABV',
'searchType':'D',
'deptYear':'2011',
'deptMonth':'12',
'deptDay':'10',
'retYear':'2011',
'retMonth':'12',
'retDay':'11',
'cabin':'E',
'currency':'NGN',
'deptTime':'',
'arrvTime':'',
'airlinePref':''}

encoded = urllib.urlencode(query)



url = 'http://www.wakanow.com/ng/flights/SearchProcess.aspx?' + encoded
user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'
headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }
req = urllib2.Request(url, encoded, headers)

response = urllib2.urlopen(req)

print 'RESPONSE:', response
print 'URL     :', response.geturl()

headers = response.info()
print 'DATE    :', headers['date']
print 'HEADERS :'
print '---------'
print headers

data = response.read()
print 'LENGTH  :', len(data)
print 'DATA    :'
print '---------'
print data
```

It all works fine, but the result i get is not what appears if i type the entire url into a web browser directly, that gives me the right result.

I'm not sure what the problem is can anyone help me out?

Comment: That request doesn't seem to work for me.  This is the value of ```url``` when the code runs: [link](http://www.wakanow.com/ng/flights/SearchProcess.aspx?retYear=2011&airlinePref=&adults=1&searchType=D&retDay=11&retMonth=12&arrvTime=&arrvCode=ABV&deptDay=10&trip=RT&deptMonth=12&currency=NGN&deptCode=LOS&deptYear=2011&infants=0&deptTime=&children=0&cabin=E).  It just hangs.  (Actually I can't seem to connect to the site at all.)

Answer (score 2):

You're likely doing a `GET` in your browser, but in your code, you're actually doing a `POST` to a URL with the query data AND with your query data as the `POST` data. You probably just want to do a `GET`. From [this page](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request),

`urllib2.Request(url[, data][, headers][, origin_req_host][, unverifiable])`

> data may be a string specifying additional data to send to the server, or None if no such data is needed. Currently HTTP requests are the only ones that use data; the HTTP request will be a POST instead of a GET when the data parameter is provided. data should be a buffer in the standard application/x-www-form-urlencoded format. The urllib.urlencode() function takes a mapping or sequence of 2-tuples and returns a string in this format.

So, what you really want, is:

`req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=headers)`

Answer (score 1):

If the 2nd parameter (`data`) for `urllib2.Request` is provided then `urllib2.urlopen(req)` makes a `POST` request.

Use `encoded` either in url (`GET`) or as `data` in `urllib2.Request` (`POST`) not both i.e,

either `GET` request:

```
url = 'http://www.wakanow.com/ng/flights/SearchProcess.aspx?' + encoded
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=headers) #NOTE: no `encoded`
```

or `POST` request:

```
url = 'http://www.wakanow.com/ng/flights/SearchProcess.aspx' #NOTE: no `encoded`
req = urllib2.Request(url, data=encoded, headers=headers)
```

Comment: sorry i didn't quite understand you. Should i just use urllib2.urlopen(url) directly?

Comment: `urllib2.urlopen(url)` doesn't allow you to send headers. So if you don't need/want the headers in the request, go ahead, else, check my answer, which has what you will need to use.

Comment: @TiOLUWA: I've added conrecte examples to the answer.

Comment: the req object from urllib2.Request() doesn't seam to have a read() method, how do i read the data? i'm getting an AttributeError when i do req.read

Comment: @TiOLUWA: from your own code: `response = urllib2.urlopen(req)`. After that you could call `response.read()`.

Comment: thanks for your help, the site seams down now, but i've tried it out on another site and it works fine. When the site is up, i'll try again.

Comment: I've tried it again with get and post, but i still get a different result. I noticed the site first returns a page that shows 'please wait...' its the url of that page that the function 'code response.geturl()' returns, which is 'http://www.wakanow.com/ng/flights/SearchProcess.aspx?retYear=2011&...'. But on the website, the actual result page has the url  'http://www.wakanow.com/NG/flights/listing.aspx?searchId=...'.

Comment: @TiOLUWA: you could use `wireshark` (network sniffer) to see the exact content that is passing between your computer and the server.

Answer (score 0):

This url hangs. Try it with a less heavy search string.

And you may consider controlling this with a timeout:

```
import urllib,urllib2,socket

timeout = 10
socket.setdefaulttimeout(timeout)
```

Comment: i think the site is down, i can't even access the site directly form my browser now.